# While Loop in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I'm not sure why this SQL query is not working.

I'm new to SQL/PHP so please forgive.

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = " . "'Bob'" . 
    while($i < $size)
    {
        $i++; 
        echo "OR name = '"; 
        echo $array[$i] . "'";
    } . 
    " ORDER BY id DESC "
);
```

Dreamweaver gives me an error saying it is not correct but does not tell me what is wrong.

Is it possible to put a while loop into an sql command?

Comment: advice, try running your query into sql first, make it work then move it to your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not use a while in a string

```
$where = "";
if ($size > 0) 
{
$where .= " WHERE ";
}
while($i < $size)
{
$i++;
$where .= "OR name = '".$array[$i]."' ";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '".Bob."'".$where." ORDER BY id DESC";
mysql_query($query);
```

(this code is not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Woot !

You just can't write this :D

Build your `OR` condition before writing the query and it will be just fine:

```
$myCondition = " ";
while($i < $size) {
    $i++;
    $myCondition .= "OR name = '" . $array[$i] . "'";
}
mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = " . "'Bob'" . $myCondition . " ORDER BY id DESC ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is to output the string, and it won't return the string.

Something like `$str = "aaa" . echo "bbb";` won't work.

For you case, use `IN` will be better.

```
foreach ($array as &$name) {
  $name = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
}
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (".implode(',', $array).")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN(".implode( ',', $array).")";
```